# How to change `Authentication` implementation in spring-boot resource-server with opaque-token introspection?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a spring-boot resource-server configured with opaque-token introspection.

It works, but I'm now trying to opt-out `BearerTokenAuthentication` which is the type of `Authentication` build by `OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider`.

I implemented an `OpaqueTokenIntrospector` which turns introspection result into an `OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal` of my choice (implementation that is an `Authentication` too), but this is later turned into `BearerTokenAuthentication` by`OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider` and I could not find how to change this behavior.

Any clue?

### edit

Opened a ticket for that: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [feature was merged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/1efb63387f14dc7858f445884f34b70af30b85b4) on spring-security 5.8 branch.

All that is required now is to provide the resource-server opaque-token configurer with an `OpaqueTokenAuthenticationConverter` (or `ReactiveOpaqueTokenAuthenticationConverter` in webflux apps):

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(
        HttpSecurity http,
        OpaqueTokenAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter) throws Exception {

        http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken()
                .authenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);

    return http.build();
```

Comment: How can this be achieved with spring-security 5.7 or lower?

Comment: By moving to a more recent Spring Security version <:oD

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because I'm dealing with a vendor product where I have no influence on the dependency version. So I've asked the same question for version < 5.8 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77286543/how-to-change-authentication-implementation-in-spring-boot-resource-server-with)

Comment: As I described in the ticket I linked in my question, there is no way to do it (reason for me adding that feature to the framework). So, you'll have to deal with `BearerTokenAuthentication` or change your "vendor product".

Comment: I guess it should be possible by implementing a custom `AuthenticationProvider`