# How to change Authentication implementation in spring-boot resource-server with opaque-token introspection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a spring-boot resource-server configured with opaque-token introspection.

Spring security creates internally a `BearerTokenAuthentication` as a result of the authentication. How can I replace the `BearerTokenAuthentication` by any other implementation of `Authentication`?

The exact same question has been asked and answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73230717/how-to-change-authentication-implementation-in-spring-boot-resource-server-wit), for spring-security version >= 5.8.
How can the same be achieved with spring-security version 5.7 or older?

Comment: the feature was merged into the 5.8 version, wouldnt in be logical to assume that this feature did not exist before that? which means logacally again, that you cant do that pre 5.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use authenticationManagerResolver interface

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http,CustomAuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(c->c.authenticationManagerResolver(d -> customAuthenticationManager));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Component
    static class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager{
        private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
        private final OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector;

        public CustomAuthenticationManager(OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector) {
            this.introspector = introspector;
        }
        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            BearerTokenAuthenticationToken bearer = (BearerTokenAuthenticationToken) authentication;
            OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = getOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(bearer);
            AbstractAuthenticationToken result = convert(principal, bearer.getToken());//here custom extract data
            result.setDetails(bearer.getDetails());
            this.logger.debug("Authenticated token");
            return result;
        }

        private OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal getOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(BearerTokenAuthenticationToken bearer) {
            try {
                return this.introspector.introspect(bearer.getToken());
            }
            catch (BadOpaqueTokenException failed) {
                this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since token was invalid");
                throw new InvalidBearerTokenException(failed.getMessage(), failed);
            }
            catch (OAuth2IntrospectionException failed) {
                throw new AuthenticationServiceException(failed.getMessage(), failed);
            }
        }

        private AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal, String token) {
            Instant iat = principal.getAttribute(OAuth2TokenIntrospectionClaimNames.IAT);
            Instant exp = principal.getAttribute(OAuth2TokenIntrospectionClaimNames.EXP);
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = new OAuth2AccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER, token, iat, exp);
            return new BearerTokenAuthentication(principal, accessToken, principal.getAuthorities());
        }

    }
```

Comment: This works at least partly. But the problem is, that `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer`creates and adds automatically another `OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider` on top. Do you know if it's possible to prevent this?

Comment: @eztam yes,That's because we used http.oauth2ResourceServer(c->c.opaqueToken(Customizer.withDefaults())), which also caused an OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider to be created, but our custom priority is higher than this. If you don't want to create this OpaqueTokenAuthenticationProvider, maybe you can use the AuthenticationManagerResolver interface to directly return an AuthenticationManager to verify the token. I have edited the above code